# Tell find function to find first occurrence after row 36?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variable startingRow

```
startingRow = 36
```

I want to use the Cells.Find function to search for the first row after row 36 where something occurs. How do I accomplish this?

```
foundRow = wksDreamSheet.Cells.Find("Summa/Snitt", 36, , , xlByRows, xlNext).Row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
startingRow = 36
With wksDreamSheet
    Set rng = .Range(startingRow & ":" & .Rows.Count).Find("Summa/Snitt", , , , xlByRows, xlNext)
End With
```

or more reliable:

```
Dim rng As Range
startingRow = 36

With wksDreamSheet
    Set rng = .Range(startingRow & ":" & .Rows.Count).Find("Summa/Snitt", , , , xlByRows, xlNext)
End With
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    foundRow = rng.Row
Else
    foundRow = 1 ' or any other number (or msgbox with error)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and very pleased to receive your congratulations:)

Comment: Any idea why the following returns "Nothing". Set rng = wksMaster.Range("F:F").Find(id, , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext). I know that the contents of id is produced by formulas in column F

Comment: @user1283776, try `Set rng = wksMaster.Range("F:F").Find(ID, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)`